# Bulging batteries on a Nexus 4

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion

I have a Nexus 4 phone, which had battery issues, and the battery was replaced by a no-name battery from ebay. After about two months, the battery swelled/budlged out (to the point that the backside of the phone buldged out, and wouldn't stand straight on the table).

The battery was replaced again, by a "genuine" battery from ebay, and after about a month or so, it swelled/buldged up too. Another one, from a top-rated seller ended up with the same symptoms after about two months. I've used cheap chinese batteries before, and while exaggerated capacities are normal, I've never had issues with batteries expanding and swelling.

After some googling, most sites blame the chargers (ac adapters) for this, so i've verified the voltages, and were in normal usb ranges (from 4.93 to 5.05V under load), but since the charging is done by the internal circuit doing the CC/CV charge, i doubt the adapter is at fault.

How would I verify the charging circuit of a mobile phone, without any serious modifications? I'm not very familliar with battery chemisty, so what would be the most obvious cause of batteries bulging? Too high current in the CC phase? Too high voltage before switching to CV mode? Not stopping the charging process after the low current in CV mode? Or am I just extremely unlucky with ebay batteries?

Comment: You bought a crap battery!

Comment: *"the battery was replaced by a no-name battery from ebay"* .... *"the battery swelled/budlged out"* .... seems like a classic case of cause and effect to me. Buy a real genuine battery from the real genuine supplier and test that before you start looking for problems elsewhere.

Comment: I've had 3 replacement batteries bulge out after ~1 month of use. One crappy battery, ok.. two crappy ones.. bad luck.. three of them bulging out is weird for me

Comment: Did you try a battery not from ebay? You should have realised by now that if it is on ebay and says *geniune* there's a 99% chance it's a lie

Comment: "genuine" is a mistranslation from the original Chinese. It should read "complete garbage".

Comment: This doesn't just apply for batteries, but almost anything, including electronic components since this is a electronics Q&A.

Comment: If the time to reach full charge ,is less than continuous use time, the charger may be at fault.

If the phone gets hot without charger, the battery is at fault.

If the battery charge regulator inside phone does not shutoff at 90% or monitor temp correctly, the phone is incompatible with battery ESR.

Comment: "How would I verify the charging circuit of a mobile phone, without any serious modifications?" easiest way is fully charge the battery, then remove it from the phone and measure its voltage. If <4.2V the charging circuit is probably OK. Most common causes of a puffed lipo are overcharging (>4.2V/cell), high temperature (especially when fully charged) and poor quality (bad chemical mix / contamination).

Answer (score 1):

> The battery was replaced again, by a "genuine" battery from ebay

... right ...

> what would be the most obvious cause of batteries bulging?

Inferior, counterfeit, batteries.

> am I just extremely unlucky with ebay batteries?

Luck isn't involved. eBay batteries are, 99% of the time, counterfeit and actually can be quite dangerous.

You would have to be extremely lucky to get a good battery. eBay is not a reputable place to buy batteries from.

If you want to buy a new battery for a consumer device such as a mobile phone you have to buy one from a reputable retailer. That means someone that sells mobile phones on behalf of mobile phone manufacturers.

That doesn't include the pop-up "Fonez Fixed Here" shops that appear for a few weeks on many high streets and them mysteriously change overnight into a shop selling Christmas decorations. They can often be as bad as eBay (and often use the same Chinese suppliers).

If someone is trying to sell you something as "genuine" at a fraction of the real cost then either it's stolen or it's not genuine. Either way you don't want it. You're putting yourself and your family at risk of death by fire.

Comment: 1. Welcome back. 2. MIGHT be in-phone charger. Might. See my answer suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

While this question relates to a specific product the answer may be used as a guide to checking that LiIon batteries are being charged correctly.

I'll mainly address the questions you asked rather than give a lesson in ebay-ethics or likely quality. A very small sermon is mandatory.

> I have a Nexus 4 phone, which had battery issues, and the battery was replaced by a no-name battery from ebay. After about two months, the battery swelled/bulged out (to the point that the backside of the phone buldged out, and wouldn't stand straight on the table).

One of the normal failure modes for low quality junk rubbish batteries.

> The battery was replaced again, by a "genuine" battery from ebay, and after about a month or so, it swelled/buldged up too. Another one, from a top-rated seller ended up with the same symptoms after about two months. I've used cheap chinese batteries before, and while exaggerated capacities are normal, I've never had issues with batteries expanding and swelling.

SOUNDS like low quality junk rubbish batteries (here endeth the sermon)
BUT may be the phone. So ...

> How would I verify the charging circuit of a mobile phone, without any serious modifications? I'm not very familiar with battery chemistry, so what would be the most obvious cause of batteries bulging?
>
> Too high current in the CC phase?

Possibly yes.

> Too high voltage before switching to CV mode?

Possibly yes.

> Not stopping the charging process after the low current in CV mode?

Possibly yes.

SO:

You can obtain low cost USB inline monitors which display (either alternately  every few seconds or with a dual display) voltage and current. These are probably on ebay and can be obtained via eg Ali Express at low cost  usually with "free shipping".
These allow you to

- See applied voltage - should be ~= 5V. Not likely to be a problem.
- See current drawn - highly useful.

With a flat or low charged battery you can see the CC current.
From flat you can see how long this lasts for. This should charge to around 70-80% capacity if CC ~= C (eg 1400 mA for a 1400 mAh cell = C) and to say 80-90% capacity at C/2 or less. If I_cc x minutes/60 approaches the mAh rating of the cell then the CC mode is not exiting.
If CC mode terminates and Ichg starts falling you are in CV mode.
Measure Vbat (probably by removal)- it should be in the 4.0 - 4.2V range. Definitely should not be over 4.2V.

Run in CV mode. This should terminate when I drops to C/k where k varies with aggressiveness of charge. C/2 is conservative and reasonable. C/4 is also OK. C/10 (eg 140 mA for a 1400 mAh cell is rather aggressive).
If Ichg in CV mode falls to below C/10 but charging continues then the charger is faulty. Whether in or out of phone)

At NO time should Vbat be > 4.2V. (A FEW modern cells may allow 4.3V but this is rare). If Vcell > 4.2V summat agale - and walking away wit hands in sight is advised.

The inline meter MAY require a small current to operate but ideally will not display this.

To see cell only current turn phone off while charging.

If you can measure Vcell on charge so much the better = you may be able to add short wireso allow battery voltage to be measured while in place. Soldering ortwisting around terminals probably not needed - splay wire end slightly and push into place between battery contact and phone terminal. DO NOT SHORT the battery withe the test wires !!!!

---

Example only - NOT a recommendation

Ali Express [USB V&I dual display](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/2015-Hot-USB-Detector-Current-Voltage-3V-9V-LED-Tester-2-Hubs-2-Row-Shows-Monitor/32581888272.html?spm=2114.30010308.3.136.4eyznO&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10065_10068_10084_10083_10080_10082_10081_10060_10061_10062_10056_10055_10054_10059_10078_10079_10073_10096_10070_10100_10052_423_10050_10051_424,searchweb201603_9&btsid=10b2f491-1143-47bf-9f63-0e7cb6350a6b) $US3.29 - free shipping.

[image]